# The driver detected a controller error on \Device\CdRom0

Tags: optical-drive

I opened the CD-ROM drive on my server and blew out the dust.  After it closed, I noticed that this error was appearing in Event Viewer:

> The driver detected a controller error on \Device\CdRom0

Can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

OS: Windows XP SP3

drive: LG WH14NS40 Bluray writer

I got these errors on Event Viewer:

-The driver detected a controller error on \Device\CdRom0

-The device, \Device\Ide\IdePort2, did not respond within the timeout period.

-An error was detected on device \Device\CdRom0 during a paging operation.

Cause: crappy made-in-China SATA cable

Solution: changed the cheap SATA cable by a decent, **ASUS** SATA cable.